# Issue converting aspx file to image

Tags: wkhtmltoimage, tuespechkin

I've been using TuesPechkin to create images of some HTML code from my application.

I'e been using the following code successfully when using HTML, but if I try to load ASPX files instead, the code doesn't work.

```
var htmlDocument = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Dev\Git\Groups\viz\slides\Slide menu\003#Survey\form.aspx");
var document = new HtmlToImageDocument
{
    ScreenHeight = 350,
    ScreenWidth = 500,
    Format = "png",
    LoadSettings = new LoadSettings { WindowStatus = settings.WindowStatus ?? "load-complete" },
    In = htmlDocument
};

IConverter converter =
    new StandardConverter(
        new ImageToolset(
            new Win32EmbeddedDeployment(
                new TempFolderDeployment())));

var resultBytes = converter.Convert(document);
```

I have even tried to read the HTML to string and load that, but it is not working.

I am using TuesPechkin version 2.1.1.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Is it not creating an image? Is there no CSS applied?

Comment: debug your to ensure it is running and no error